# Uniqueness of Transient Node Voltages

Tags: spice, kirchhoffs-laws

Considering only transient (not DC) simulations for circuits in which every node has a capacitor path to any other node (a stack of capacitors connects any pair of nodes), and in which all initial node voltages and initial inductor currents are specified, is there always exactly one transient solution for the node voltages?

I hear about SPICE convergence problems and am looking for simple example netlists.  My above question is independent of the numerical algorithm and therefore is simply about the theory in solving Kirchhoff's Laws, but in case the answer is yes, I would still like to see example netlists which cause convergence difficulty.  I imagine that nonlinear devices, like MOS transistors in saturation with infinite differential resistance, are needed to cause such problems.

A short SPICE input file is really the best answer here.

Answer (score 1):

In the capacitor case, there is a single unique solution and SPICE will find it.

Convergence issues can arise from multiple cases:

1. model errors -- if the model for the component contains equations that are discontinuous (or are discontinuous in first or higher derivatives), SPICE may fail to converge around those locations
2. 'Stiff' equations -- if you have elements with hugely differing magnitudes -- say 1 \$  p\Omega \$ (pico ohm) and 10000 \$  G\Omega \$ in certain configurations, the floating point representation may not be able to represent all quantities with sufficient accuracy. A related case is strings with very high gain -- e.g. large numbers of inverters in series with DC feedback. In practice this rarely occurs.
3. Circuits with more than 1 solution -- e.g. in a perfectly balanced flip-flop there can be 3 solutions -- a) balanced -- each output at VDD/2, b) 1 & 0, c) 0 & 1 outputs. Without hints and starting points, SPICE may come up with the unstable equilibrium balance point. Similar issues occur in (incorrectly designed) bandgap reference circuits.
4. (non-physical) Circuits with behavioral models, no delays and 'infinite' gain -- e.g. a Schmitt trigger with input connected to the output. With zero delay in the model, there is no consistent solution.

Comment: This is a good list and increases my confidence in SPICE.   I would also add a #5 where the numerical time step causes a false ringing or eliminates a real ringing and I would explicitly expand #3 to cover ringing at an unstable pole.   I'm then interested most in SPICE examples for #3 where the instability is not a design goal (so a flip-flop would not be in my top examples, nor a ring oscillator, etc, but I know that this prioritizing is very arbitrary).